# Infinite scroll horizontally left

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date

Im currently working on a gantt chart built in angular, I'm currently at the stage where i need to load more dates into the application when the user scrolls left or right.

Triggers are fired based on scroll percentage.

```
if(position > 85){
   //load future dates
}
if(position < 15){
  //load dates in the past
}
```

and dates are worked out using the Date function in js.

The problem I have is when the dates in the past are loaded in the scroll position remains at X where X is the hot spot to load in more events, so i end up in an infinite date load scenario.

Im aware of what the problem is, however looking for a solid solution to this problem is difficult to find.

My currently approach would be to reposition the scroll bar on load based on the pixel offset of the newly loaded dates. However I'm worried this may cause a "stutter/jank" and just seem a bit unpleasant all round.

Any solutions or thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://livepipe.net/control/scrollbar) might help.

Essentially, if I understand what you are after, the section to focus on is the event which inserts some text and then recalculates the scroll position.